# Mocking <Query /> from react-apollo

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, react-apollo, react-testing-library

I have the following component:

```
import { Query } from 'react-apollo';

const Comp = ({ getQuery, variables }) => {
  <Query query={getQuery} variables={{ ...variables }}>
    {({ loading, error, data }) => {
      if(loading){
          return <div>Loading...</div>;
      } else if(error){
          return <div>Error!</div>;
      }else{
          return <div>{data}</div>;
      }
    }}
  </Query>;
};
```

Which is currently working

I am having troubles mocking this:

```
    {({ loading, error, data })
```

for testing proposes I want to mock the component and not create a mockProvider, how can I mock it?

Comment: Why would you mock that? It's part of the component you're testing, `Comp`, not part of `Query` (to which it's the children prop).

Comment: Because I want to make unit testing of the component, I know how <Query /> works, I only care to test the code inside the <Query />, the code I show is a shorter version of the original code.

Comment: Sure, but the code you're saying you want to mock is *part* of that component. It's unclear what you're currently doing and what the specific problem is, please give a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the proper way to do this.

This kind of components are known as **Render props components** more info [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) and [here](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-render-props)

The mock:

```
jest.mock("react-apollo", () => {
  const ReactApollo = require.requireActual("react-apollo");

  const MyModule = {
    ...ReactApollo,
    Query: ({ children, ...rest }) => (
      <mock-my-component {...rest}>
        {typeof children === "function"
          ? children({
              data: {user:"name"},
              loading: false,
              error: false,
            })
          : children}
      </mock-my-component>
    ),
  };
  return MyModule;
});
```

[This](https://cborchert.blog/this-week-i-learned-how-to-mock-a-render-props-component-in-react) blog post help me a lot to get the correct answer.